# Spring - Passing Listener via RMI

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, rmi, event-listener

### Basis

I have several projects, which implement a caching service - each its own, and each one is almost the same as the others. I have coompressed and shortened the existing cacheservices into a single project containing two different cache services - one for basic objects, and one for complex objects (which extends the basic service). I have created 2 projects - one to deploy as a .war-file and the API-project for this.

The entire application runs on a JBoss AS 7.1 "Thunder" with the latest JDK 7.

### Problem

One class in particular requires to be notified whenever an old cache entry is deleted. For this, I implemented a notification procedure using CleanupListeners.

*CleanupListener.java*

```
public interface CleanupListener extends Remote {

    public abstract boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) throws RemoteException;

    public abstract void notify(Object removedObject) throws RemoteException;

}
```

*necessary implementations in the cache service*

```
public void registerCleanupListener(CleanupListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

private void fireCleanupEvent(Object removedObject) {
    for (CleanupListener cleanupListener : listeners) {
        try {
            if (cleanupListener.supports(removedObject.getClass())) {
                cleanupListener.notify(removedObject);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException re) {
            LOGGER.error("Remote Listener not available", re);
        }
    }
}
```

The listeners are managed via a `private final HashSet<CleanupListener>`
The project which needs to be notified uses this implementation of the interface:

```
@Component
public class CleanupEventListener extends UnicastRemoteObject implements CleanupListener {

    protected CleanupEventListener() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Resource
    private ClassRequiresNotification notifyMe;

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return SupportedObject.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void notify(Object removedObject) {
        notifyMe.someMethod((SupportedObject) removedObject);
    }
}
```

and a registration bean:

```
@Component
public class CleanupEventListenerRegistrator {

    @Resource
    private CleanupEventListener cleanupEventListener;

    @Resource
    private BasicCacheService cacheService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cacheService.registerCleanupListener(cleanupEventListener);
    }
}
```

The remote services are exported via SpringBean:

```
@Bean
public RmiServiceExporter basicCacheServiceExporter(BasicCacheService basicCacheService) {
    RmiServiceExporter cacheService = new RmiServiceExporter();
    cacheService.setService(basicCacheService);
    cacheService.setServiceName(BASIC_CACHE_SERVICE_NAME);
    cacheService.setServiceInterface(some.package.BasicCacheService.class);
    return cacheService;
}
```

and registered via XML-Config:

```
<bean id="basicCacheService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="lookupStubOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="basicCacheService" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="some.package.BasicCacheService" />
    <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

### Exception

So, whenever I try to call the expected methods, I get one of two Exceptions:

Either I get a `NoSuchObjectException` (rare) or, much more common a `ClassNotFoundException` wrapped in an `UnmarshalException`

### What I did

I already consulted the JavaDocs, googled massively and have sifted through several questions here, however to no avail. I found a bit of info that the standard property `rmi.codebase` is set to `true`, and this might require some rewriting of code, however we are already using RMI at another place in the projects, and it does work fine there. Adding a SecurityManager breaks the rest of our Application (due to external prerequisites) and calls the `NoSuchObjectException`.
Answers within StackOverflow so far have yielded "this is a problem with the codebase", "you need to install a securityManager", "the classes have to have the same name and be in the same package" and of course "it's the codebase". I am mentioning this one twice, since it does appear quite often yet not a single mention as to how to deal with a codebase problem accompanies it.

### Additional Info

I am not sure if this is important, but here's some more info:
The cacheservice-project is configured in java code, the projects which use the service are configured in XML.
The Listener-Interface is not exported vie Annotations or XML-Beans, since several Posts (including at least one here) hinted that this will export the class, but keep listening only on server-side, which is not what I want.
I have also tried to make the `CleanupListener`an abstract class, which in itselt extends `UnicastRemoteObject` but that did not work out either - in fact, it was worse than what I have now.
I am writing and testing the application in eclipse.
Assembling and publishing to server is done by gradle in the command line.

### Question

Does anyone know what the problem here is, and how to actually solve it? It is getting quite aggravating when everything I do is either running into an exception or is "yeah that's a codebase error", since both do not help at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Actual answer

Okay, this is simultaneously embarrassing and relieving. First of all...

#### The good news

The Listener-Interface as described above works. It is registered on the server-side, and when called, fires a notification to the client, which then may act accordingly. So, if you have been looking for an answer to the whole "passing a listener"-problem, there you have it.

#### The bad news

however is that I have been quite ignorant to certain facts. Among other things, what the term *codebase* actually covers. In my particular case, the problem was that the cacheservice itself had no dependencies on the other projects, which (custom) classes it should preserve. So technically, the *codebase* actually **was** the problem - due to lacking dependencies in the `build.gradle`.

I hope I dodn't waste anyone's time on this, if so, please accept my apologies, and hopefully, this question helps someone else sometime.

Comment: you mean "what was the use of the class" or "has that class been changed"?